# How do I sort by a field inside an object inside a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, object

I currently have a list of items and inside each of those items is an Object with a field that I'm trying to sort the original list by, I cannot figure out how to do this sort for the life of me! Please help.

```
List<ViewModel> Entities
--ViewModel Entity
---string GroupName
```

So I'm trying to sort the Entities list by the field GroupName inside the Entity inside the Entities List. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) (Linq To Objects actually)

```
Entities.OrderBy(e => e.GroupName);
```

Make sure you add `using System.Linq`. Also see [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby).

If the entities are coming from Entiry Framework then just tack the `OrderBy(...)` on there, *before* you create a list so you let the database do the sorting.